# .NET: User.IsInRole not working from within Visual Studio

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, windows-authentication, roles

I have a .NET MVC 4 application that uses Windows Authentication. I want to check whether the user is a member of a particular Active Directory group and if so, display an additional menu option:

```
            if(User.IsInRole("WellnessAdmins"))
            {
                <li>
                    <b>@Html.ActionLink("Admin","Admin","Home")</b>
                </li>
            }
```

When deployed to the server, this works fine; the Admin link is displayed. However, when I launch the application from Visual Studio, the Admin link is not displayed. My local computer and the server are on the same domain. Why this weird behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using IIS Express make sure that you have enabled Windows Authentication and disabled Anonymous Authentication in the properties of your project:

[image]

Comment: I have switched to IIS Express and applied these settings, and now it seems that IIS Express can't get the user's identity at all. User.Identity.Name is empty, but again when deployed to IIS 7 everything works fine.